# Pyinstaller and Tkinter issue

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller

If I type `pyinstaller --noconsole  --onefile --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' name_kmn.py`

I get this when I open file
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
2020-01-23 22:33:06.832 name_kmn[18608:125609] -[PYGSDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd8736e350
2020-01-23 22:33:06.832 name_kmn[18608:125609] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PYGSDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd8736e350'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3232e8ab **exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6859f805 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff323adb61 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff32292adf ___forwarding_** + 1427
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff322924b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x00007fff3fc15f24 TkpInit + 655
    6   Tk                                  0x00007fff3fb95cbb Tk_Init + 1706
    7   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x0000000118733e35 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    8   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x000000011872f84f _tkinter_create + 1056
    9   Python                              0x000000010c281834 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 488
    10  Python                              0x000000010c280dc0 _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 41
    11  Python                              0x000000010c3162b4 call_function + 628
    12  Python                              0x000000010c30f28f _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6767
    13  Python                              0x000000010c316b15 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
    14  Python                              0x000000010c280a00 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 444
    15  Python                              0x000000010c281b07 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 131
    16  Python                              0x000000010c2bee96 slot_tp_init + 80
    17  Python                              0x000000010c2bbbc2 type_call + 172
    18  Python                              0x000000010c280c36 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    19  Python                              0x000000010c31631a call_function + 730
    20  Python                              0x000000010c30f32a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6922
    21  Python                              0x000000010c316b15 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1698
    22  Python                              0x000000010c30d77d PyEval_EvalCode + 51
    23  name_kmn                            0x0000000105880e69 name_kmn + 7785
    24  name_kmn                            0x000000010588141a name_kmn + 9242
    25  name_kmn                            0x000000010587fb74 name_kmn + 2932
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort      /Users/olegkalasnikov/PycharmProjects/TestProject/dist/name_kmn

Help me please!